# BigQuery SQL: Average, geometric mean, remove outliers, median

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm calculating the average time to get a reply on Stack Overflow, and the results make no sense.

```
#standardSQL

WITH question_answers AS (
  SELECT * 
    , timestamp_diff(answers.first, creation_date, minute) minutes
  FROM (
    SELECT creation_date
      , (SELECT AS STRUCT MIN(creation_date) first, COUNT(*) c
         FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` b
         WHERE a.id=b.parent_id
        ) answers
      , SPLIT(tags, '|') tags
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` a
    WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM creation_date) > 2015
  ), UNNEST(tags) tag
  WHERE tag IN ('java', 'javascript', 'google-bigquery', 'firebase', 'php')
  AND answers.c > 0
)

SELECT tag
  , COUNT(*) questions
  , ROUND(AVG(minutes), 2) first_reply_avg_minutes
FROM question_answers
GROUP BY tag
```

[image]

How should I calculate the average time?

Answer (score 7):

*Update 2019:* How about sharing some [persisted public UDF](https://medium.com/@hoffa/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83)s?

First one, median:

```
SELECT fhoffa.x.median([1,1,1,2,3,4,5,100,1000]) 

3.0
```

---

Indeed - getting an average time to get answers on Stack Overflow of above 100 hours (>6000 minutes) seems wrong - and is largely driven by outliers.

Instead of doing a simple `AVG()` you could get:

- The geometric mean: `EXP(AVG(LOG(GREATEST(minutes,1))))`
- The mean after removing outliers: `AVG(q) FROM (SELECT q FROM QUANTILES(q, 100) LIMIT 80 OFFSET 2))`.
- The median: `all_minutes[OFFSET(CAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(all_minutes)/2 AS INT64))]`

The results make way more sense if you use any of those alternatives:

[image]

As you can see here, in this case removing outliers give us results similar to the geometric mean - while the median reports even lower numbers. Which one to use? Your choice.

```
WITH question_answers AS (
  SELECT * 
    , timestamp_diff(answers.first, creation_date, minute) minutes
  FROM (
    SELECT creation_date
      , (SELECT AS STRUCT MIN(creation_date) first, COUNT(*) c
         FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` b
         WHERE a.id=b.parent_id
        ) answers
      , SPLIT(tags, '|') tags
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` a
    WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM creation_date) > 2015
  ), UNNEST(tags) tag
  WHERE tag IN ('java', 'javascript', 'google-bigquery', 'firebase', 'php', 'sql', 'elasticsearch', 'apache-kafka', 'tensorflow')
  AND answers.c > 0
)

SELECT *  EXCEPT(qs, all_minutes)
  , (SELECT ROUND(AVG(q),2) FROM (SELECT q FROM UNNEST(qs) q ORDER BY q LIMIT 80 OFFSET 2)) avg_no_outliers 
  , all_minutes[OFFSET(CAST(ARRAY_LENGTH(all_minutes)/2 AS INT64)  )] median_minutes
FROM (
  SELECT tag
    , COUNT(*) questions
    , ROUND(AVG(minutes), 2) avg_minutes
    , ROUND(EXP(AVG(LOG(GREATEST(minutes,1)))),2) first_reply_avg_minutes_geom
    , APPROX_QUANTILES(minutes, 100) qs
    , ARRAY_AGG(minutes IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY minutes) all_minutes
  FROM question_answers
  GROUP BY tag
)

ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

---

Bonus `MEDIAN()` [UDF function from Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649330/bigquery-moving-median-calculation).

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION MEDIAN(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT
    IF(
      MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 0,
      (arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] + arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]) / 2,
      arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]
    )
  FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x) AS arr FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x)
));
```

Comment: The median you've used is discrete, not interpolated/continuous so could be lower than the real middle but might not be significant, probably better to use `PERCENTILE_CONT(x, 0.5) OVER() AS median` in standardSQL see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#percentile_cont

Comment: The way you've excluded outliers assumes a right skewed distribution; a fair assumption given time-to-respond is akin to latency modelling/duration analysis. It might be similar to a generalized gamma-distribution, but before you consider which measure of the central tendency to use, it would be worth binning those percentiles and graphing it to see roughly what the distribution looks like. Using robust measures of central tendency (like median) and scale (like MAD instead of StdDev) already reduce the impact of outliers. Trimming outliers to percentiles 3-83 is removing a lot of the tail!

Comment: May you please explain why you choose to trim the quantiles between 3-83 , isn't it affecting the results to get a mean which is affected by most low values of the quantiles ?

Why not use the full range except for the first and last quantile ?
which includes only the extreme values...