# Moving (Rolling) Median with BigQuery

Tags: sql, median, google-bigquery

I currently have a table in BigQuery that contains some outliers and would like to calculate the moving median for this table.

Example table:

```
port - qty - datetime
--------------------------------
TCP1 - 13 - 2018/06/11 11:20:23
UDP2 - 15 - 2018/06/11 11:24:24
TCP3 - 12 - 2018/06/11 11:24:27
TCP1 - 2  - 2018/06/12 11:24:26 
UDP2 - 15 - 2018/06/12 11:35:32
TCP3 - 200- 2018/06/13 11:45:23
TCP3 - 14 - 2018/06/13 11:54:22
TCP3 - 13 - 2018/06/14 11:55:33
TCP1 - 17 - 2018/06/15 11:43:33
UDP2 - 12 - 2018/06/15 11:55:25
TCP3 - 14 - 2018/06/15 11:26:21
TCP3 - 11 - 2018/06/16 11:55:46
TCP1 - 14 - 2018/06/17 11:34:33
UDP2 - 15 - 2018/06/17 11:43:24
TCP3 - 13 - 2018/06/17 11:47:54
and ...
```

I would like to be able to calculate a 7-day moving median on the various ports at 11hrs using bigquery standard SQL.
I have tried calculating the moving average, but have realised that the calculations are affected by the 'outlier'.

I do not know how to write the SQL query to calculate the moving median. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

(this is the closest thread that i could find on this topic: [BigQuery - Moving median calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649330/bigquery-moving-median-calculation) but I need bigquery to be able to get the qty from the table as I do not know exactly the number of qty for each specific day)

Comment: too broad - you might want to present expected result based on input example in your question

Answer (score 2):

I think this is close enough to what you want:

```
select t.*,
       qtys[ordinal(cast(array_length(qtys) / 2 as int64))]
from (select t.*,
             array_agg(qty) over (partition by port
                                  order by datetime_diff(datetime, datetime('2000-01-01'), day)
                                  range between 7 preceding and current day
                                 ) as qtys
      from t
      where extract(hour from datetime) = 11
     ) t;
```

Medians are a bit tricky when there are an even number of rows in the result set.  This chooses an arbitrary value.

Comment: hi, would like to ask what does "order by datetime_diff(datetime, datetime('2000-01-01'), day)
                                  range between 7 preceding and current day" do?? Will it affect the calculation for the moving median that is 1 month before?

Comment: @taN . . . `array_agg()` does not support a windowing `range` clause on dates/datetimes/timestamps.  But it does support a windowing `range` clause on numbers.  So this converts the the dates to numbers.