# Calculating time_diff between rows with same id in GoogleBigQuery

Tags: sql, database, statistics, google-bigquery

I'm practicing my SQL skills with BigQuery and I'm trying to calculate the time difference between bike rents for each bike. Basically, I want to calculate time_diff for each different ID, for each pair of a row with same bike id. I'm trying to find the median of the time_diff distribution for each bikeid For now, I have:

```
SELECT bikeid,
       DATE_DIFF(date(start_time), date(prev_start_time), day) AS Tempo,
       OrderCount
FROM ( SELECT bikeid,
              start_time, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY bikeid ORDER BY start_time ASC) OrderCount,
              LAG(start_time) OVER(PARTITION BY bikeid ORDER BY start_time ASC) prev_start_time
       FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` 
     ) 
ORDER BY bikeid, start_time
```

I'm using the public BigQuery dataset `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips`, and my result is weird because it doesn't show any bike id(I Already expect a lot of nulls (0) as date_diff, because the database register timestamps and sometimes the bike is rent a lot of times in one day).

```
    | Linha | bikeid | Tempo | OrderCount |
    |   1   |  null  | null  |     1      |
    |   2   |  null  |  57   |     2      |
    |   3   |  null  |  1    |     3      |
```

Comment: Do you just want to find what is the median number of minutes a given bike was rented for?

Comment: @khan I want to find the distribution of time differences between bike rentals for each bike, after that, I want to find the median of the distribution for each bike. But I also want to learn how to construct this distribution.

Comment: Check this for median and other metrics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981353/bigquery-sql-average-geometric-mean-remove-outliers-median

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of nulls in bikeid column. You are seeing nulls because ASC order will fetch nulls first. 
There are few option you can choose
•   You can change your order by clause to DESC on bikeid
SELECT bikeid,
       DATE_DIFF(date(start_time), date(prev_start_time), day) AS Tempo,
       OrderCount
FROM ( SELECT bikeid,
              start_time, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY bikeid ORDER BY start_time ASC) OrderCount,
              LAG(start_time) OVER(PARTITION BY bikeid ORDER BY start_time ASC) prev_start_time
       FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips`
     )
ORDER BY bikeid desc, start_time
•   You can remove null bikeid by adding where clause “where bikeid is not null”
SELECT bikeid,
       DATE_DIFF(date(start_time), date(prev_start_time), day) AS Tempo,
       OrderCount
FROM ( SELECT bikeid,
              start_time, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY bikeid ORDER BY start_time ASC) OrderCount,
              LAG(start_time) OVER(PARTITION BY bikeid ORDER BY start_time ASC) prev_start_time
       FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips`
       where bikeid is not null
     )
ORDER BY OrderCount desc, bikeid desc, start_time

Comment: thanks! It worked! Do you have any idea of how to get only the median for each bikeid distribution?

Answer (score 0):

The average is the total difference divided by one less than the number of rentals.  So, you don't need window functions:

```
SELECT bikeid,
       DATE_DIFF(MAX(DATE(start_time)), MIN(DATE(start_time)), day) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0) as avg_period
FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` 
GROUP BY bikeid ;
```

The above fixes your query and answers your question.  I'm not so sure that it does anything useful, because bikes are rented multiple times per day (that's the point of a public bike rental programs).

At the very least, you can use a smaller unit of time:

```
SELECT bikeid,
       TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(start_time), MIN(start_time), second) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0) as avg_period_in_seconds
FROM  `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` 
GROUP BY bikeid ;
```

Comment: Actually, I don't need the average I need the Median. Let me edit the post! but thanks!

Comment: @LeandroEleutério . . . Editing the post would be rude, because it would invalidate this answer.  This answers the question you have asked.  If you have another question, ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm really thankful for your answer but note that at my original post I didn't mention calculating the average or nothing similar. I said I wanted to calculate the time difference between each bike rent. I just edit the post to make more clear that I don't want the average I want the distribution of days differences between bike rents. The median is a really good data informative, I show what number divide our data into two groups, the top 50%, and the bottom 50%. In this case, I would not be useful because of the timestamp but, as I said, I practicing for registers with dates.