# How to calculate median over multiple columns in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm creating a query to calculate median visits from two different websites by day.

The output should look like the following:

```
+------------+---------+---------------+
|    date    | website | median_visits |
+------------+---------+---------------+
| 2019-04-01 | A       | median_value  |
| 2019-04-01 | B       | median_value  |
| 2019-04-02 | A       | median_value  |
| 2019-04-02 | B       | median_value  |
| 2019-04-03 | A       | median_value  |
| 2019-04-03 | B       | median_value  |
+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Here is what my table (there are 20,000 rows) looks like:

```
+------------+---------+--------+
|    date    | website | visits |
+------------+---------+--------+
| 2019-04-01 | A       |   10.0 |
| 2019-04-01 | B       |   14.0 |
| 2019-04-02 | A       |   85.0 |
| 2019-04-03 | A       |   75.0 |
| 2019-04-02 | B       |    3.0 |
| 2019-04-02 | B       |   45.0 |
| 2019-04-01 | A       |   12.0 |
| 2019-04-03 | A       |   44.0 |
| 2019-04-01 | A       |   99.0 |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

What would be the most efficient way to query for the desired output? I am currently using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, website, median_visits
FROM
 (SELECT  date, website, PERCENTILE_CONT(visits, 0.5) 
  OVER(PARTITION BY date, website) AS median_visits
  FROM table)
```

Comment: Beside a missing group by in your current query what's the problem with the output? What are you looking for fix or this is a general question about efficiency?

Comment: Your method is fine, with the right syntax.

Comment: @TamirKlein - i think explicit `GROUP BY` is not needed in OP's current query as it is already there implicitly via `DISTINCT` (which is GROUP BY by all fields in select statement)

Comment: @TamirKlein Yes, this was regarding efficiency as I need to use it at a much larger scale. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL - I cannot claim it is the best. I cannot even guarantee that it is better - but based on my testing I see better execution plan and slots usage. So, you can try and see with your data

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date, website, 
  (SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(visit, 0.5) OVER() 
    FROM UNNEST(visits) visit LIMIT 1
  ) AS median_visits
FROM (
  SELECT date, website, ARRAY_AGG(visits) visits
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY date, website
)
```

Comment: Also found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092758/how-to-calculate-median-of-a-numeric-sequence-in-google-bigquery-efficiently) related to median calculation and performance related to it.